# html, css. blank space at the right side of the browser

Tags: html, css

I realize that every once a while when I create a website, there is always a tiny little blank space on the right of the page.

Can't really figure what is the root of the problem in css. Some said it is the browser issue. But I think there is a fix. Does anyone know why it is like that and how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Please see the right side of the area in gray color below:
[image]

How to make the gray area to disappear?

Comment: Without seeing the code how can anybody tell where is your problem?\

Comment: aaa I never got a blank space while I was creating. post your code please.

Comment: @Dibya is right, but if I had to guess, I would say that you need to include a reset style sheet.

Comment: Old online game, right now on stackoverflow: Guess the code!

Comment: Wait I am hacking his PC to get the code :)

Comment: @Mr_Green.. Please post the code soon..

Comment: hey tisywacky it was just joke. take it light :)

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to post the link. the css file is quite big now, hard to separate the codes and post it. please take a look at the link inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly need to use some sort of CSS Reset style sheet if you haven't already. Try inserting one of the options from [here](http://www.cssreset.com/) into your CSS. It will most likely mess up a few things, but once you correct the issues, everything should be more or less normalised across the browsers.

One of the things they do is reset `<body>` and `window` margins/padding etc. which would possibly fix the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this, it makes your web page is view in middle of the screen. 
and may i know your page is fixed width layout or full width layout?

```
margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding

```
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
```

to body

Comment: Why are you guessing so much??

Comment: sometimes i m also got an error like that...but that is in all the sides...so...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Yahoo API YUI reset 3 sheet. It completely resets everything for all browsers. Also to fix your problem  you will need to look at the overflow property on y. You can disable scrolling, disable overflow, etc. If the problem persists you could even create a vector or other element to use a clipping mask on the site if all else fails. Comment if you decide to use this approach I will elaborate.